# Why control+click doesn´t work in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I was programming correctly in Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers - 2021-03 and one day, suddenly, control+click to access variable, method or class references stopped working.

Now I'm using F3 to access them, but I prefer control+click because it's more comfortable.

I've tried touching the hyperlink options but nothing I've tried works.

Here is the image of error log window when I use control+click:
[image]

And here below is the error when I click twice for accessing some element.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting handlers: {[org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.PinEditorHandler@169043e3,  for 'org.eclipse.ui.window.pinEditor',  in WorkbenchContext, activeWhen=AndExpression [children=[WithExpression [variable=activeEditorId, children=[<instanceof value="java.lang.String"/>]], <test property="reuseEditor" plug-in activation: lazy/>]], active=true, sourcePriority=1074003968, participating=true]} vs {[org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.PinEditorHandler,  for 'org.eclipse.ui.window.pinEditor',  in WorkbenchContext, activeWhen=AndExpression [children=[WithExpression [variable=activeEditorId, children=[<instanceof value="java.lang.String"/>]], <test property="reuseEditor" plug-in activation: lazy/>]], active=true, sourcePriority=1074003968, participating=true]} in: PartImpl (org.eclipse.e4.ui.compatibility.editor)  removeOnHide org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditorContext
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService$HandlerSelectionFunction.compute(LegacyHandlerService.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ValueComputation.get(ValueComputation.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.internalGet(EclipseContext.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.get(EclipseContext.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.lookUpHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.setEnabled(HandlerServiceHandler.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.setEnabled(Command.java:856)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.canExecute(HandlerServiceImpl.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.canExecuteItem(HandledContributionItem.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem$1.run(AbstractContributionItem.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.AbstractContributionItem.updateItemEnablement(AbstractContributionItem.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolItemUpdater.run(ToolItemUpdater.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runTimer(Display.java:4124)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.messageProc(Display.java:3256)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3624)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)
```

Comment: Eclipse 2021-03 is four releases behind. Please upgrade. If your issue persist, delete the error log (the errors shown in your screenshot are a couple of days old), reproduce the issue and if any, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_ (please show the complete error, not only the stack trace). Have you installed additional plugins?

Comment: @howlger Regarding the errors being a couple of days old - they were new when the screenshot has been originally added (the post was in the [staging ground](/help/what-is-staging-ground) before being published).

Comment: @dan1st Thanks for the info. I didn't know about that. The staging ground seems not be helpful here: outdated software for no reason, no exact description to reproduce, cropped screenshot and incomplete error message.

Comment: @howlger It's 2023, so that's *8* releases behind.